Reset actionButton in module
I have a simple shiny mechanism question and I am not understanding why and how I could answer it.
I have an app where an observeEvent action is inside a module server. This server is associated to a tabPanel.
My problem is : if I click on the button, close the modal, change panel and then go back to Home one, the modal shows again. How to prevent this behavior ? Should I "reset" the actionButton value or is it a reactivity mistake ?
library(shiny)
mod_test_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("click_me"), "Click")
  )
}

mod_results_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    observeEvent(input$click_me, {
      showModal(modalDialog(id = "mymodalstudy", "Here is a modal"))
    })
    
  })
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tabsetPanel(id = "mytab",
              tabPanel("Home", mod_test_ui("Test")),
              tabPanel("Other", p("Other content"))))



server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$mytab,{
    if(input$mytab == "Home") {
      mod_results_server("Test")
    }
  })
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


The moduleServer() has to be created once.
I fill its name in react$loaded_modules to verify if it exists.
You can see that:

the timestamp stays identical at its creation time  if you comme back to a modal yet created.
but if you change the text input, it's changed but the timestamp remains the old one

library(shiny)

mod_test_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("click_me"), "Click")
  )
}

mod_results_server <- function(id, blatime,input_bla_react){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    observeEvent(c(input$click_me,input_bla_react), {
      if (!(is.null(input$click_me)) &&  input$click_me >0 ) {
        showModal(modalDialog(id = "mymodalstudy", 
                              paste("Here is a modal ",id, blatime, input_bla_react(), sep =" " )
        ))
      }
    })
    
  })
}


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  textInput("mytext", label='Text Input', value='nothing'),
  p('Loaded modules'),
  verbatimTextOutput('modules'),
  tabsetPanel(id = "mytab",
              tabPanel("Home", mod_test_ui("Home")),
              tabPanel("OtherA", p("Other content"),mod_test_ui("OtherA")),
              tabPanel("OtherB", p("Other content"),mod_test_ui("OtherB")),
              tabPanel("OtherC", p("Other content"),mod_test_ui("OtherC")),              
              selected ="Home"
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  react <- reactiveValues(
    loaded_modules=c()
  )
  
  output$modules <- renderPrint({react$loaded_modules  })
  
  observeEvent(input$mytab,{
    
    selected_tab=ifelse (is.null(input$mytab),"Home",input$mytab)
    
    if   (length(intersect(react$loaded_modules,selected_tab)) ==0 ) {
      react$loaded_modules<- unique(c(react$loaded_modules,selected_tab))
      mod_results_server(selected_tab,Sys.time(),reactive(input$mytext))
    }
  },
  ignoreNULL = FALSE)  
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


It is working only because selected = "Home". If you change to selected = "Other" the modal do not appear. I would like a solution working however the number of tabs, and each one has its own module server.

changes done to answer to your comment :)

Changes of variables names.  verbatimTextOutput('modules') to see the instances of modules loaded.
